# how to send multiple checkbox data with `|` delimeter using codeigniter form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, input

I want to send multiple checkbox data using `|` delimiter in CodeIgniter form

In my form, I use the `checkbox` to select multiple data:

```
  <form method="get" action="<?PHP echo base_url();?>search">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="1234">Sylhet 
        <input type="checkbox" name="cats" value="1235">Dhaka
        <button>Search Now</button>
  </form>
```

now it sends like: `search?cats=1234&cats=1235`

but I want it to send like `search?cats=1234|1235`

Comment: If you use `name="cats[]"`, you will get `search?cats[]=1234&cats[]=1235`. But you can access data derectly by using `$_GET["cats[]"]`. I think you need to use javascript to achiev your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send it using `name="cats[]"` and get your checkbox data in Controller:

```
$cats = $this->input->get('cats',true);
```

the variable `$cats` will return an array. if you need `data1|data2` string, you can construct it in your controller by looping each array.

However if for somewhat reason you need to need to pass the checkbox data in `search?cats=data1|data2` format, you can use a hidden field and change the hidden field value everytime you checkbox changed.

Comment: I got this point and fix it, before your answer btw thanks @LbG